# Angular doesn't send the right data to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

```
private currentInfo:string[];
private useruid: string;
...
constructor(private AngularAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db:AngularFirestore) { }

...

sendInfo(text:string){
    this.readInfo();
    this.currentInfo.push(text);
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({
        Info: this.currentInfo
    })
}
...
readInfo(){
    this.useruid = this.AngularAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).snapshotChanges().subscribe(a=>{
      const data = a.payload.data() as {name:string, Info:string[]};
      data.Info.forEach(element => {
        this.currentInfo.push(element);
      });
    })
}
```

Good afternoon, I can't find the solution to this problem,
I have 1 method **readInfo( )** that reads the current user info from firebase, this method works apparently when i try it aside from the other part of the code, however i want to update this info with some *text:string*, however when i run it, it reads the database simultaneously as it writes the new info *this.currentInfo*. So firebase doesn't update with the current info.

As an example, imagine I currently have as currentInfo = ["a","b","c"] and as text = "d", after y run the method **sendInfo( )**, only ["d"] is written in firebase.

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

The `snapshotChanges()` method here is async so the writing is done before the reading is over. Then move your `update` statements into the `subscribe` call :

```js
sendInfo(text:string){
    this.useruid = this.AngularAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).snapshotChanges().subscribe(a=>{
      const data = a.payload.data() as {name:string, Info:string[]};
      data.Info.forEach(element => {
        this.currentInfo.push(element);
      });
      // Add the text to currentInfo and save
      this.currentInfo.push(text);
      this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({
        Info: this.currentInfo
      })...
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendInfo(text:string){
this.readInfo(); //As Olivier Depriester said this function is called but you are not waiting for the data to be read.
this.currentInfo.push(text);
this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({
    Info: this.currentInfo
})
```

}

for infinte loop issue, declare another copy of this.currentInfo and use one for the loop and another for the final values.